# Solving Recurrence Relation with backwards substitution

Tags: recurrence-relations, substitution

I am calculating the effiency class of this

R(n) = 2R(n−1)+2.

with the base case of R(1) = 1

using backwards substitution.

My equations came out to

4R(n-2) + 6

8R(n-3) + 14

16R(n-4) +30

I don't see how i can get an equation from this... Is it incorrect?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "effiency class"? I mean, I guess it's a typo for "efficiency class" or something, but I don't know what that means, either. 2) $4R(n-2)+6$ is an expression, not an equation. 3) What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $R(m)=T(m)+b$

$\implies T(n)+b=2\{T(n-1)+b\}+2=2T(n-1)+2b+2$

Set $2b+2=b$

Answer (score 0):

When you’re unwrapping a recurrence this way, it’s usually a bad idea to simplify by actually doing the arithmetic. Instead you should have

$$\begin{align*}
R(n)&=2R(n-1)+2\tag{*}\\
&=2\big(2R(n-2)+2\big)+2\\
&=2^2R(n-2)+2^2+2\tag{*}\\
&=2^2\big(2R(n-3)+2\big)+2^2+2\\
&=2^3R(n-3)+2^3+2^2+2\tag{*}\\
&=2^3\big(2R(n-4)+2\big)+2^3+2^2+2\\
&=2^4R(n-4)+2^4+2^3+2^2+2\tag{*}\;.
\end{align*}$$

At this point the starred lines should suggest the conjecture that

$$R(n)=2^kR(n-k)+2^k+2^{k-1}+\ldots+2^2+2=2^kR(n-k)+\sum_{i=1}^k2^i\tag{1}$$

for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$. If this is true, then for $k=n-1$ we’ll have

$$R(n)=2^{n-1}R(1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2^i=2^{n-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2^i\;,$$

which you should be able to express in closed form. Once you have that closed form, you should prove by induction that it’s correct, since it was based on the **conjecture** $(1)$, which could conceivably be wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much this was extremely clear

Comment: @Squaddy: You’re very welcome.